# When to determine when a fruit tree graft has failed?

Tags: fruit-trees, grafting

I had my first go at grafting at the beginning of April, i.e. about 5 weeks ago. This was on apple trees. The temperature has been above freezing ever since, typically 5-15 degrees. The tree itself was entering bloom at the time of graft and appears healthy, putting out new growth. There has been no sign of any growth from the grafts whatsoever.

If the grafts have failed, when and how will I know this? And what should I do in that case? Leave them on? Take them off?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide detailed, close-up, in-focus pictures of your grafts. We'll be looking for signs of "callousing" or healing material indicating that the graft and tree have joined. Mid-bloom seems a bit late for any grafting other than "budding."